# Are common design patterns applicable for microservice architectures?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture, microservices, software

As part of my master's thesis, I am currently working on a framework for building microservice-based service systems. Based on my research, I am able to define important design criteria that the system must fulfill. In order to make these design criteria usable in practice, I want to draw on proven design patterns. However, since I have little experience in the topic of design patterns so far, I would like to ask two questions:

1. Are the common design patterns (*Creational, Structural, Behavioral*) suitable for describing microservice-based applications, since they are already several years old?
2. Can the design patterns be combined with each other?

As a concrete example (see image below): The architecture at hand provides for several independent services, which in turn are built on individual microservices (service n). A client request to one of these services is handled by a central microservice that delegates the request to the appropriate microservice behind this *Facade*. In addition, each service can access a central DataLake that holds, eg., required master data for service execution. This one falls (according to my current knowledge) under the categorization as a *Singleton*. Is this design methodologically feasible?

[image: (Very) Basic first draft of the application design]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The classic “Gang of Four” design patterns are about solving recurring *code-level problems* through object-oriented techniques. These remain relevant *within* a microservice, though of course some patterns have been subsumed by core language features, and not every codebase uses an object-oriented style. The creational/structural/behavioural classification makes most sense on a code-level.

But these GoF patterns are not architectural patterns. They are not about how different programs communicate. Microservices are one common architectural pattern to structure a complex software system. Martin Fowler has [written extensively](https://martinfowler.com/microservices/) about different aspects of the microservice pattern/architectural style and related architectural patterns. In this different context, different pattern classifications might be useful. E.g. in *Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture*, Fowler uses some similar classifications like *Object-Relational Structural Patterns*, but also introduces novel categories like *Offline Concurrency Patterns*. In any case, these classifications are just a tool for structuring a collection of patterns, they are not an inherent property of patterns.

Some problems that we have on a code level re-appear similarly on an architectural level. So it is perfectly reasonable to describe one microservice as a *facade* for another, though the term *API gateway* is more common in this context. And just like the *singleton* pattern can be used on a code-level to select a globally unique instance within a process, a distributed microservice system will have its own solutions for facilitating *service discovery* (probably DNS, or a distributed consensus algorithm). There's actually a very deep similarity between “objects that invoke methods” and “microservices that make HTTP requests” so some lessons from object-oriented design are applicable in a microservice architecture as well.

While it can be interesting to notice similarities between different pattern in different software engineering contexts, it's probably not too helpful to dwell on this too much. Patterns are tools for communicating design decisions and best practices. But patterns are not building blocks. If you find it helpful to think and talk about the “data lake singleton” then do that, but you don't have to view your entire design through the lens of patterns. Don't try to force patterns into a perfectly acceptable design.

Can patterns be combined? Absolutely, yes. Patterns address recurring design problems, but problems are interwoven and related. For example in the classic GoF patterns, the *composite* and *visitor* patterns are often used together. One component might participate in multiple patterns for different aspects of its behaviour, e.g. a *strategy* that also serves as a *proxy*.

In summary:

- avoid viewing a microservice architecture through the lens of object-oriented patterns

  - although there might be some interesting relationships
- there are separate (but less well-known) patterns for architecture-related problems
- focus on building software that works, not on adding patterns

Answer (score 0):

"Microservices" are indeed the new buzz word; but its actual fundamental architecture goes back decades. To answer your point, just because something is old, does not make it any less relevant or any less useful. Patterns exist to solve problems in a consistent way - those problems exist regardless of the architecture.